# Why am I not logged out of meta when I log out of a parent site?

Tags: support, stackexchange-2.0

When I click "logout" on a meta site and click "logout" to confirm that I want to log out, I am also automatically logged out of the parent site. However, the converse does not happen. Is this by design?

Answer (score 1):

I bet that being logged out on the main site when you logout on meta was an old bug. Currently, you will not be logged out on the main site when you logout on the meta site, also the other way round won't happen. To me, this makes perfectly sense.